# Simplify function for Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have this code, which in my opinion is too long. And I was wondering if there's a way for me to simplify or shorten it.

I have this helper-function `swap` which takes in two lists of integers and returns them after swapping a number from on to the other All lists have 5 ints in them, so I fill in with zeroes if there are less than that.

It looks like this:

```
-- Takes in two lists and moves one non-zero int from one to the other
swap :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
swap xs ys
  | xs == ys = [xs, ys]                                             -- If both lists are all zeroes
  | all (==0) ys =                                                  -- If the second list is all zeroes
    let
        e = head $ filter (/= 0) xs                                 -- First non-zero element from first list
        newX = replicate (length xs - length (filter (/= 0) xs) - 1) 0 ++ tail (filter (/= 0) xs)
        newY = tail ys ++ [e]
        in
            [newX, newY]
    | otherwise =
    let
        e = head $ filter (/= 0) xs                                 -- First non-zero element from first list
        newX = replicate (length xs - length (filter (/= 0) xs) + 1) 0 ++ tail (filter (/= 0) xs)
        newY = replicate (length (filter (==0) ys) - 1) 0 ++ [e] ++ drop (length xs - length (filter (/= 0) ys)) ys
        in
            [newX, newY]
```

I am using it in my function below, which is the function I feel like is too long:

```
move :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
move a b ints
  | a == b = error "a and b cannot be the same integer"
  | a == 1 && b == 2 =
    let
        fst = ints !! (a-1)
        snd = ints !! (b-1)
        swapped = swap fst snd
        in
            [head swapped, last swapped, last ints]
  | a == 1 && b == 3 =
    let
        fst = ints !! (a-1)
        snd = ints !! (b-1)
        swapped = swap fst snd
        in
            [head swapped, ints !! 1, last swapped]
  | a == 2 && b == 1 =
    let
        fst = ints !! (a-1)
        snd = ints !! (b-1)
        swapped = swap fst snd
        in
            [last swapped, head swapped, last ints]
  | a == 2 && b == 3 =
    let
        fst = ints !! (a-1)
        snd = ints !! (b-1)
        swapped = swap fst snd
        in
            [head ints, head swapped, last swapped]
  | a == 3 && b == 1 =
    let
        fst = ints !! (a-1)
        snd = ints !! (b-1)
        swapped = swap fst snd
        in
            [last swapped, ints !! 1, head swapped]
  | a == 3 && b == 2 =
    let
        fst = ints !! (a-1)
        snd = ints !! (b-1)
        swapped = swap fst snd
        in
            [head ints, last swapped, head swapped]
  | otherwise = error "a and b must be either 1, 2 or 3"
```

This function takes in two ints and a list consisting of 3 lists of ints, where each list has 5 integers, so a sample input would be f.ex

```
[[1,2,3,4,5],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]] or 
[[0,0,0,4,5],[0,0,0,2,3],[0,0,0,0,1]] or 
[[0,0,3,4,5],[0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0,2]]
```

So $a$ and $b$ can only be either 1,2, or 3. Giving me $2^3=6$ different cases to consder. Even If manage to get it down to two cases $a>b$ and $b>a$ I still get too many lines of code compared to what I expect is proper for Haskell. Is there any way of shortening this code?

Comment: In the first code block, is the last guard indented a bit too much?

Comment: Yes, It was an error on my part, I didn't indent properly, but it should be indented as much as the other guards.

Comment: I give it go in a later today or on Sunday. I see plenty of simplification opportunities.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a full answer yet, but the start of one. Look how I removed all code duplication into *where* blocks. There are still plenty of opportunities of simplification.

```
-- Takes in two lists and moves one non-zero int from one to the other
swap :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
swap xs ys
    | xs == ys = [xs, ys]                                             -- If both lists are all zeroes
    | all (==0) ys =                                                  -- If the second list is all zeroes
      let
        newX = replicate (length xs - length nonZeroXs - 1) 0 ++ tail nonZeroXs
        newY = tail ys ++ [e]
      in
        [newX, newY]
    | otherwise =
      let
        newX = replicate (length xs - length nonZeroXs + 1) 0 ++ tail nonZeroXs
        newY = replicate (length (filter (==0) ys) - 1) 0 ++ [e] ++ drop (length xs - length (filter (/= 0) ys)) ys
      in
        [newX, newY]
  where
    nonZeroXs = filter (/= 0) xs
    e = head $ filter (/= 0) xs                                 -- First non-zero element from first list
```

The only difference between *newX*s is the signal of the the final addition. Which suggests that the entire decision block might be not be at it's best place.

```
move :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
move a b ints
    | a == b = error "a and b cannot be the same integer"
    | a == 1 && b == 2 = [head swapped, last swapped, last ints]
    | a == 1 && b == 3 = [head swapped, ints !! 1,    last swapped]
    | a == 2 && b == 1 = [last swapped, head swapped, last ints]
    | a == 2 && b == 3 = [head ints,    head swapped, last swapped]
    | a == 3 && b == 1 = [last swapped, ints !! 1,    head swapped]
    | a == 3 && b == 2 = [head ints,    last swapped, head swapped]
    | otherwise = error "a and b must be either 1, 2 or 3"
  where 
    fst = ints !! (a-1)
    snd = ints !! (b-1)
    swapped = swap fst snd
```

Have a good look on the above and run some tests. I don't have the time to test it myself right now.

Comment: This is more than helpfull! Thank you. I'll look over it now.

Comment: @pedrofurla Is it possible to do this by using cases? And if so, how would you do it?